# Why hasn't the Stack Exchange iOS app been updated for the iPhone Max display?

Tags: discussion, ios

The application is not adapted to new displays, and 2 years have passed...

Answer (score 10):

The app hasn't been updated since a while; users have been complaining about this since the iPhone X came out in 2017: [Stack Exchange app iPhone X optimization](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302876/295232)

However, this issue won't be addressed, as the apps have been abandoned. [Quoting a Stack Exchange developer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/295232):

> We are not providing any further support for the mobile apps. There will not be any more builds made for either the Android or the iOS app (even for breaking bugs). We encourage all mobile users to use the responsive website. We hope to continue to incrementally improve the user experience for mobile users.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to open source it? Or is the API deprecated as well?

Comment: Yes, but they won't; [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315791/295232) is [status-declined].

Answer (score 4):

See [Stack Exchange for iPhone is here!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/05/08/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/):

> ## What about feature […]?
>
> While the application currently has some awesome features, it doesn’t have everything. If you find something wrong or missing, please let us know. Use your fancy new app to post a question on [Meta using the ios-app tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ios-app).

Comment: Graham is correct, the app belongs to all stack sites, so the main meta is where to ask. https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ios-app